# Action on a group descends to an action on its factor group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $A$ and $B$ be groups and $N\unlhd A$ is a normal subgroup of $A$. Suppose that $B$ acts on $A$; that is, there exists a group homomorphism (not necessarily monomorphism) $$f:B\to\mathrm{Aut}(A)\text{,}$$ where $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ is the [automorphism group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism#Automorphism_group) of $A$.

My question: Under what condition does $f$ descends to an action on the factor group $A/N$? That is, under what condition does $f$ induces a group homomorphism $$\overline{f}:B\to\mathrm{Aut}(A/N)\text{?}$$

Comment: Is it that $\forall b\in B, (f(b))(N)\subseteq N$?

Comment: Yes it is. Look at here, it might be helpful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_subgroup

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt for the conclusion! In the article http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409307.pdf, for the proof of Proposition 3.1 I think the author basically only proved that $f(b)(N)\subseteq N$ (of course, with different notations), am I correct?

Comment: Well you do need the stronger condition $f(b)(N) = N$ for all $b \in B$, but in fact that follows from $f(b)(N) \le N$ and $f(b^{-1})(N) \le N$, so you are correct. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you @DerekHolt for the clarification!

Comment: @DerekHolt, actually I have another related question and am not sure if I should ask in a separate post: If $M\unlhd B$ is a normal subgroup of $B$, under what condition does $f$ induce an action of $B/M$ on $A/N$ (that is, a group homomorphism $\tilde{f}:B/M\to\mathrm{Aut}(A/N)$)?